# How can i make my program not calculate same thing twice

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a program that merges your name and your birth date to one string then outputs every possibility. I made a code it outputs random shuffled possibility that i want. But it outputs same thing twice or more. How can i make it calculate a possibilty only once. Here is my code;

```
    import random

a = input("enter your name").lower()
b = input("enter your birth date")
x = 0

def generator(name, birth):
        merge = name + birth
        final = random.sample(merge, len(merge))
        final1 = "".join(final)
        print(final1)


while x < 100 :
    call = generator(a, b)
    x = x + 1
```

Comment: Do you want to avoid calculating the same thing twice, or only avoid having duplicates in the result?

Comment: For the issue "it outputs [the] same thing twice or more" I would remove the print(final1) statement from the generator function, and make a new printf after the call to generator.

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be to dont generate your combinations random,

just make 2 lists and systematically run through them.
and if you shuffle those lists first you get a somewhat random result. Shure there will be patterns to find but if thats ok for you that would be a way to go